# Why can't my host machine connect to my virtual guest machine via HTTP protocol?

Tags: centos, virtualbox, macintosh

I have successfully installed [CentOS7](https://www.centos.org/) as a guest on [VirtualBox for mac](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads).

I have also installed a Tomcat 7 as shown in the picture below and I can successfully access http://localhost:8080 from Firefox *within* the CentOS virtual machine.

However, I am not able to access http://localhost:8080 *outside* the centOS virtual machine (i.e. I am not able to access the website from my host Yosemite web browsers like Safari or Firefox).

Here are my centOS7 network settings from within Virtual Box:

[image]

With the above network settings, I am able to connect to the internet *within* the CentOS virtual machine. But I can't connect to the host machine.

Answer (score 3):

With these network settings, the webserver will not be running on the `localhost` interface of the host machine. Your host machine in essence has become a router behind which the guest machine is accessing the network. If you look at the IP address of the guest machine it will probably be something like `10.10.10.100`. You can try surfing to (in this example) http://10.10.10.100:8080 on the host machine and, depending on your firewall and network settings, you should get to your webserver.

The better solution is to change guest machine's network settings to use bridged mode, so the IP address of the guest machine and the host machine will be the same. At that point you should be able to surf to http://localhost:8080.

[The VirtualBox Networking Manual](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html) has more details on the different networking modes available and what they do.